# Poppler Compilation with windows and cmake gets error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, poppler

I want to compile poppler for windows with Cmake and VS2008. but when i want to configure it with cmake the following error is produced:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:83 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package)
```

How can I fix this problem? actually how can i compile it for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will have to install FreeType package for windows.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm